# Firefox AJAX with Transitions Running Slowly

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, firefox

So I've designed a webpage using AJAX to give it the sleek feel of a single-page application, and it works (very roughly) like this.

Markup:

```
<a class="js-ajax-link" href="/new-page">New Page</a>
<div class="container js-container">
    ... content goes here ...
</div>
```

Scripts:

```
const ajaxLink = document.querySelector('.js-ajax-link');
const container = document.querySelector('.js-container');

ajaxLink.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    container.classList.add('container--out'); // animate old page out

    swapContent();
    // swapContent is an ajax request using the HREF of '.ajaxLink'
    // then swaps the innerHTML of '.js-container' with the
    // corresponding '.js-container' on the new page.

    container.classList.remove('container--out'); // animate new page in
});
```

Styles:

```
.container{
    opacity: 1;
    transition: transform 1s, opacity 1s;
}
.container--out{
    transform: scale(2) blur(50%);
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Now, keep in mind this is an over-simplified version of my code to quickly illustrate what I'm doing, not an exact representation.  What I'm doing here works very well in Safari, Edge, Chrome, even in Samsung Internet.  The only odd man out here is Firefox, and I can't seem to identify the issue.

From this code, you would expect to click any ajax-enabled link to watch the page zoom, blur, and fade, then a new page would do the reverse back into the frame.  This happens as expected in other browsers, but in Firefox, it initially freezes, hesitates to transition just one or two of the styles, then goes blank for an excessive period, and then finally catches the tail end of a transition or two back in.  It's clumsy, ugly and jarring.  Does anyone have any ideas why this would be happening, and if so, how can I address it?  Is it a problem with CSS, AJAX, or both?

Comment: `over-simplified version of my code to quickly illustrate what I'm doing` is it complete and verifiable example that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: you do realise that you `add('container--out');` and then `remove('container--out');` ... without ever waiting for `swapContent();` to complete ... if `swapContent();` contains synchronous XMLHttpRequest, (which I suspect it does) then you may find that you are getting a warning in the console about deprecated synchronous XMLHttpRequest - try rewriting your code to use asynchronous AJAX (after all, the first A in Ajax stands for Asynchronous

Comment: In short, please show the code for `swapContent` function - that's quite relevant to your question

Comment: swapping back and forth between Resume and About looks fairly similar in both Chrome and Firefox (to me) - though Resume likes to disappear much faster than About! ... it's only when swapping to/from Home or Portfolio that there's a *very* visible difference. Portfolio fits in page, no scroll bars, Home has `scrollingFX` - just wonder if either of those things are responsible

Comment: although looking back at this particular part, I probably should be using a callback function of some kind. My loading screen is kind of meaningless as it is.

Comment: You're right!  It IS worse on those pages in particular.  Still isn't as smooth between Resume and About on my machine, but Home is way worse.  It's also worth noting that I've been going back and forth between mobile Firefox and Mac Firefox.  Mobile Firefox is a disaster all around, but all other mobile browsers handle it fine.

Comment: scrollingFX runs a forEach loop every 16 milliseconds.  That's pretty costly on performance, I'm sure, though I don't know if that's the root of the issue yet.  Faster code is never a bad thing though, if you can see a way around using that loop.

Comment: I would look into using `requestAnimationFrame` instead of `setTimeout(runScrollingFX, 16);` ... i.e. `const runScrollingFX = () => {
    applyScrollToggleRules(scrollToggleRules);
    passScrollToCSS();
    requestAnimationFrame(runScrollingFX); // should run at 60 fps
  }` - also, it looks like every 16ms you run passScollToCSS ... which would create more and more `requestAnimationFrame` for calling `updateCSSVariables` - profiling your page I did notice a hello of a lot of requestAnimnationFrame calls!

Comment: oh, no, ignore that last remark about animation frames

Comment: see if [this minor rewrite of scroll-fx](https://jsfiddle.net/fn1kao97/) helps .. and [this updated version](https://jsfiddle.net/fn1kao97/1/) uses `.setProperty` rather than `.cssText+=` - setting a single property rather than adding to the cssText *may* be more performant

Comment: I would also, instead of just calling `runScrollingFX` after you declare it, call it using `requestAnimationFrame(runScrollingFX);` - that way every iteration of that function is done as a result of `requestAnimationFrame`, not just from the second an on